# Masking using Nuget Uranium UI

Tags: nuget, maui

I try to find some way to use a Mask (brazilian ID "XXX.XXX.XXX-XX") in TextField of Nuget Uranium UI, but i dont find anything..

How can I do that?

I tried to use the ToolKit "MaskedBehavior" but its not working.

```
<material:TextField
    x:Name="txtCpf"
    Title="CPF"
    FontFamily="MontserratMedium"
    TextChanged="txtCpf_TextChanged"
    TitleColor="#902E2E2E">
    <material:TextField.Behavior>
        <toolkit:MaskedBehavior Mask="XXX.XXX.XXX-XX" />
    </material:TextField.Behavior>
</material:TextField>
```

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Never mind.. 

It was just put "EntryBehaviors" Instead of "Behavior" only..

Comment: Please don't show code as images, always use text.

Answer (score 0):

Have to use "EntryBehaviors" Instead of "Behavior"

Like this:

```
<material:TextField
    x:Name="txtCpf"
    Title="CPF"
    FontFamily="MontserratMedium"
    TextChanged="txtCpf_TextChanged"
    TitleColor="#902E2E2E">
    <material:TextField.EntryBehaviors>
        <toolkit:MaskedBehavior Mask="XXX.XXX.XXX-XX" />
    </material:TextField.EntryBehaviors>
</material:TextField>
```